# select xarray dataset data between two datetimes getting outside bounds

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have an hourly dataset like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 14, latitude: 82, longitude: 68)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-04-15 ... 2021-04-15T13:00:00
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 23.67 23.75 23.83 23.92 ... 30.25 30.33 30.42
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 47.0 47.08 47.17 47.25 ... 52.42 52.5 52.58
Data variables:
    u          (time, latitude, longitude) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(14, 82, 68), meta=np.ndarray>
    v          (time, latitude, longitude) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(14, 82, 68), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    history:  2021-11-16 09:10:08 GMT Hyrax-1.15.3 http://dev.qrms.net/openda...
```

and I am trying to select times I need using **Dataset.sel(time=slice(date.time, date.time))**.

```
ds.sel(time=slice(datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 15, 1, 12),datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 15, 7, 24)))
```

The problem is that I need these dates to be included in the resultant data, so my desired result is the outer boundaries:

```
slice(datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 15, 1),datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 15, 8))
```

I do not want to modify my dates manually because if I use a dataset with daily data (for example) the code will break. So I would like something more general based on getting the previous and next index in the dataset.

Is there any argument or method to make this selection automatically? I tried to use **method** and **tolerance** arguments of **Dataset.sel()** but seems that these options are not compatible using **slice()**.

Thank you all in advance!
best regards!

Comment: it's unclear what you want the results to be. If you have say a year of monthly data indexed by the first of the month, and you slice with `slice("Feb 15", "June 15")`, you want the result to return the Mar 1, Apr 1, May1, and Jun1 data, but you want to relabel the outer coordinates Feb 15 and June 15? Why?

Comment: and if this is indeed your question, then you have multiple questions in 1. you *can* use method and tolerance to interp and sel, but you're also trying to relabel the values along the sliced dimension - just do that in another step. Please make an attempt to do what you're trying to do and ask another more focused question if you get stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @MichaelDelgado for your answers, let me try to explain better using your first example:
If I have a monthly dataset with data indexed every first of the month and I slice with two dates as you mentioned ´´´ slice("Feb 15", "June 15")´´´ I want to obtain the minimum period of data that include these two dates. Feb 1. Mar 1, Apr 1, May 1, Jun 1, Jul 1. I do not want to relabel anything... sorry for my bad explanation, hope this comment clarifies my initial question...